# Java WebApp Configuration Backup and Restore

Tags: java, tomcat, backup, restore

I have a Java Spring MVC web Application. And it has some configuration and properties files.

There is a directory, let's say, ***myappconf***. Inside that there are configuration and property folders. Inside that some files are there.

```
myappconf
  |
  |---conf
  |    |
  |    |__ settings.xml
  |    |__ nodes.xml
  |
  |---prop
       |
       |__ app.properties
```

I want to take backup of the entire folder into another location. I already have Quartz implemented to run some other Jobs. I can use the same for taking backups also. To a specified location I can copy the entire folder on a specific interval or when any file is changed.

I am running the application in tomcat.

In case, the application is crashed, or the server is failed, I want to install a new application in the server and it should restore the configuration. The folder will have some data also. I want to restore all.

**I am not aware of how to restore it. Has anybody implemented something like this? or anybody has some Guidelines for Backup and restore?**

Thanks

Comment: Stop tomcat, copy files, and start tomcat afterwards.

Comment: I know that. But it should happen programmatically

Comment: Its difficult to say whether this can be done Programmatically or not. As your program may also need this configurations, which are not present in new application.

Comment: Backup is ok. But restoring is the problem. I can stop and start tomcat manually with a fresh war file. But it needs to decide whether to restore the files or start with fresh configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in this manner -

1. If you can save state of application each time its loaded/deployed in database OR in a file, that is it freshly installed or restored..
2. If you are using linux platform, go and update `startup.sh` file which is executed when tomcat is started.
3. Assuming you are running only one application in your tomcat instance, you may check the file or database entry which you created in step 1 while startup server.
4. If that entry says that any previous configuration exist, just deploy that in your application, if not, start a fresh application.

This will continue recursively until you manually remove the entry created in step-1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I think it is better to store the state in database.

Comment: For that, you have to fetch entry from database using shellscript as your war file may not be extracted while you want to check the state. :-)

Comment: The application will have an Id in the database as so many copies of application will be running in multiple systems. So when the application starts, it will have the same id as the previous one and with that I can check in database and restore, (Like normal apps). No need of shell script. I can use Java itself. Or which is better?

Comment: If the code which is written in Java for fetching the entry will inside the WAR, then you cannot check database and restore. If still you want to do it, you have to restart tomcat one more time.

Comment: Yeah, some configurations will load when starting tomcat only, so I may need to restart the tomcat to apply the new values. So I better use shell script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64218/discussion-between-ved-and-iprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can simply copy the files in your "exploded war" directory.  You can use quartz if you wish, or you can use any file system backup tool.  The later may be easier, because it has restore capabilities.

In the event that you do go with your own tooling (ie quartz), to "restore" you would shutdown your tomcat instance, copy the files back into place, optionally overwriting the old ones, and turn tomcat back on.  Tomcat reads from the exploded war files, so you'll be good to go.

Edit: ideally, you would want to shutdown tomcat (gracefully) before copying off your files, to ensure that if any changes for those files that were in memory were flushed -- but, in practice, this is rarely an issue with these kinds of files (my opinion).

Comment: In case the application is crashed, then Quratz will also won't work right? Only restore is the problem.
I can start the tomcat manually after installing a fresh application in tomcat webapp folder. But how do I know it should restore the old configurations and data or it is a new app just installed with fresh configurations? Do I need any flag set in some configuration in a separate directory or in database? Chance is that the configuration files can also be corrupted.

Comment: I assumed you would have used quartz to copy off those files to another directory, preferably keeping the same file structure.  On restore, you can copy your application as you said, then copy those files back from where you copied previously.

Comment: I can use Quartz to take backup. Sometime, i can install the application as fresh one in tomcat and start it. And sometime when I need to restore I use the same procedure. Copy war file to tomcat and start it. But I need to check whether it is starting as a fresh application or I need to restore old configurations. This is my view. But not sure this is good idea or not.So I asked here to have some guidelines.

Comment: It seems to me that you know when you're doing a restore --- because something bad happened...and you're doing a restore.  Likewise, you know if you're doing a fresh install.  Because you, the "admin", have the context, simply do the right thing based on that context.  No need to complicate your code, increasing probabilities for bugs, for something that seems well suited for fairly simple documentation.